# I am trying to get rid of spaces on a numpy grid

Tags: python, numpy

i am trying to get rid if unnecessary space on a numpy grid

This is my code:

```
import numpy as np
def make_grid():
    grid = np.full((6, 7), " ")
    return grid
grid = make_grid()
print(grid)
```

this is what it outputs full and empty:

```
[['1' '1' '1' '1' '1' '1' '1']
 ['1' '1' '1' '1' '1' '1' '1']
 ['1' '1' '1' '1' '1' '1' '1']
 ['1' '1' '1' '1' '1' '1' '1']
 ['1' '1' '1' '1' '1' '1' '1']
 ['1' '1' '1' '1' '1' '1' '1']]


[[' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ']
 [' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ']
 [' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ']
 [' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ']
 [' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ']
 [' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ']]
```

what i would like full and empty:

```
[['1''1''1''1''1''1''1']
 ['1''1''1''1''1''1''1']
 ['1''1''1''1''1''1''1']
 ['1''1''1''1''1''1''1']
 ['1''1''1''1''1''1''1']
 ['1''1''1''1''1''1''1']]


[[' '' '' '' '' '' '' ']
 [' '' '' '' '' '' '' ']
 [' '' '' '' '' '' '' ']
 [' '' '' '' '' '' '' ']
 [' '' '' '' '' '' '' ']
 [' '' '' '' '' '' '' ']]
```

how do i get rid of those spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this:

```
import numpy as np

def make_grid():
    board = np.full((6, 7), " ")
    return board
grid = make_grid()

print(str(grid.tolist()).replace("', '", "''").replace("], [", "]\n ["))
```